# how to call function from cli command magento 2

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line, command

How can call function from block to cli command magento 2
here is my cli command class

```
class Hicustomer extends Command
{
 

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('cloudways:hicustomer');
        $this->setDescription('Demo command line');
        parent::configure();
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        
       //call function from block
        $output->writeln("Hi Customer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this command :

> php bin/magento cloudways:hicustomer

To call block file you need to do like this :

```
class Hicustomer extends Command
{
 
    protected $myblockobject;

    public function __construct(\Vendor\Extension\Block\Mycustomblock $myblockobject)
    {
       $this->myblockobject = $myblockobject;
       parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('cloudways:hicustomer');
        $this->setDescription('Demo command line');
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        
       $myblockobject = $this->myblockobject->create()->MyCustomFunction();

       //call function from block
        $output->writeln("Hi Customer");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! when I run this command how can I do for run my block function? This is real?

Comment: you need to do the logic into the execute method which you want to call.

Comment: ok and then how to do when i call cli command work that function in block file?

Comment: if you want to call the your block file function then you can declare that into constructore and then use that object when you want.

Comment: Can you write expamle in your answer?(edit it)

Comment: I update my answer, please check.

Comment: I change your code for me, but its not working. Maybe need to add any code into block file ?

Comment: In above code you need to put your real block class and there function name,  run the caching and all and then need to check.

Comment: I do that but when I try to clean cache its thrown error "There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.", but when I comment that code cache clean working. How can do that?